# Executing the SFDX Update command to update the CLI to latest version is not working

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, update, issue

I'm trying to run the `sfdx update` command in `Windows 10` and every time it gives me the following log:

> PS C:\Windows\system32> sfdx update
>
> sfdx-cli: Updating CLI... already on latest version: 7.94.3-a4e7c7955b

This is version released on April 1, and since then I have tried updating to latest release every week, and I could not get to the latest release, which I think now is `51.12.0 (May 13, 2021) - CLI 7.101.0`

The CLI Repository says this is the latest version as  well:
https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/blob/main/releasenotes/README.md

How can I update to latest release of SFDX CLI, can some one guide me?

Comment: Can you try `sfdx update stable` ? Thanks

Comment: still same result `sfdx-cli: Updating CLI... already on latest version: 7.94.3-a4e7c7955b`

Comment: @Swetha - Thanks for having looked into it then and I found out recently that `sfdx-dev-server` plugin was the cause of this. I've added that as an answer to this question of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ultimately, I posted comment on a similar bug posted on GitHub CLI Repo - [link](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/254#issuecomment-850287447) - and got a resolution from there by another user suggesting to uninstall a plugin on my local machine.

Found out that it was due to `sfdx-dev-server` plugin. Had to `uninstall` the plugin and then ran `sfdx update` command to update my CLI to latest version and it ran successfully!

Answer (score 0):

Did you install sfdx-cli with windows installer ?
If yes, you can:

- uninstall using windows uninstaller
- run `npm i sfdx-cli -g`

And everytime you need an update, use `npm i sfdx-cli -g` to upgrade to the latest version

And to be sure to always have the latest version of sfdx-cli and useful plugins, you can add [VsCode SFDX-Hardis extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NicolasVuillamy.vscode-sfdx-hardis) to be notified when updates are available :)

Note: I am the main contributor of this open-source extension, and also CTO of Hardis Group Salesforce Team

[image]

Comment: That may be a great extension - I can't say because I haven't used it. But from my view, although some people will decipher it as such, a ':)' does not constitute an actual disclosure.  From [Help Center > Expected Behavior](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/behavior): _"Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers."_ Would you please edit your answer to add disclosure info?

Comment: Answer edited :)